# How to escape bracket in code block of markdown

Tags: markdown

This is the markdown code I write

```sql
%sql 

select * from members where name rlike '[aeiou]{{3}}'
```

But Actually, in the web page, it is displayed as

[image]

Comment: My guess is that your document is being passed through a templating preprocessor. What tools are you using? Perhaps Jekyll?

Comment: I use jekyll, is this due to the preprocessing ?